# Check date between two dates with spring data jpa and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I need select date between two values in spring data jpa.

```
   SELECT * FROM Device WHERE create_date >='2019-08-16' and 
   create_date <='2019-08-17';
```

I have this model :

```
  CREATE TABLE `device` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_date` date DEFAULT NULL

   @Entity
   public class Device implements Serializable {

   private java.sql.Date createDate;
   }
```

I tried many variants.

```
  public interface DeviceRepository extends JpaRepository<Device, Long> {


  List<Device>getDevicesByCreateDateIsGreaterThanEqual
  AndCreateDateIsLessThanEqual(Date from, Date to);

  public final static String FIND_BY_CREATE_DATE =
  "SELECT a FROM Device a " +"WHERE a.createDate BETWEEN :x AND :y";

  @Query(FIND_BY_CREATE_DATE)
  List<Device> getXY(@Param("x") Date x, @Param("y") Date y);

  @Query("select a from Device a where a.createDate >= :date1 and 
  a.createDate <= :date2")

  List<Device> findAllWithCreationDateBetween2(
  @Param("date1") Date date1, @Param("date2") Date date2);

  @Query("SELECT a FROM Device a WHERE a.createDate >= ?1 
  AND a.createDate <= ?2")

  List<Device> findAllWithCreationDateBetween(Date from, Date to);

  @Query("SELECT a FROM Device a WHERE a.createDate >= ?1 
  AND a.createDate < ?2")
  List<Device> findAllWithCreationDateBetween(Date from, Date to);
```

If I have in MySQL database java.sql.Date in format 2019-08-17. 
If I select from 2019-08-16 to 2019-08-18 it works perflectly. 
If I select from 2019-08-17 to 2019-08-18 it works perflectly.

If I select from 2019-08-16 to 2019-08-17 no result return. 
If I select from 2019-08-17 to 2019-08-17 no result return.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have tried everything, except for the kitchen sink:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Device WHERE create_date BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime")
List<Device> findAllDevicesWithDateRange(
    @Param("startTime") Date startTime, @Param("endTime") Date endTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same result.

I tried this :

```
@Query("FROM Device WHERE createDate BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime")
List<Device> findAllDevicesWithDateRange(
        @Param("startTime") Date startTime, @Param("endTime") Date endTime);


Hibernate: 
/* 
FROM
Device 
WHERE
createDate BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime */ select
    device0_.id as id1_6_,
    device0_.create_date as create_d5_6_,

from
    device device0_ 
where
    device0_.create_date between ? and ?
```

Example : startDate = 2019-08-19, endDate = 2019-08-19. No result. If I add one day to endDate(2019-08-20) returns rows with createDate = 2019-08-19.

Comment: Is this an answer? If not, consider removing it, and editing your question as appropriate.